# VBA Count SpecialCells

Tags: excel, vba

Good evening,
count the filtered cells

```vb
 x = Sheets("test").AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
```

I pass on the x variable and would like to know in column D the number of times Year & Month & "*" occurs.

```vb
MsgBox Range("D2:D" & x).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).CountIf(Range("D2:D" & x), Year & Month & "*")
```

Unfortunately, I get a runtime error 438
Can you help me?

Comment: A `Range` doesn't have a `CountIf` method. That said, I don't think you can use `CountIf` on a potentially non-contiguous range.

Comment: Didn't manage to combine the cell type (xl .....) with the content. But there is another way. Lasts maybe a little longer.

Comment: Didn't manage to combine the cell type (xl .....) with the content. But there is another way. Lasts maybe a little longer.